# Java-JBoss-Maven: Error getting jboss-as-client 5.0.1.GA Maven

Tags: java, jboss, client, maven

Iam using the JBoss Server 5.0.1.GA, Eclipse and Maven to write a JBoss Client program.

I added the following lines to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
  <type>pom</type>
  <version>5.0.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

But now iam getting this error messages:

```
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-client:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact cglib:cglib:jar:2.1.3:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact jacorb:jacorb:jar:2.3.0jboss.patch5-brew:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-iiop:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-server:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.microcontainer:jboss-kernel:jar:2.0.4.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-server:jar:client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact sun-jaxb:jaxb-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-bootstrap:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.security:jbosssx:jar:2.0.2.SP6:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-system-jmx:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-system:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-security:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.javaee:jboss-jacc-api:jar:1.1.0.GA_SP1:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ws.native:jbossws-native-saaj:jar:3.0.5.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact javax.security:jaas:jar:1.0.01:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.javaee:jboss-jca-api:jar:1.5.0.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact jpl-util:jpl-util:jar:1.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact jpl-pattern:jpl-pattern:jar:1.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.naming:jnpserver:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact gnu-getopt:getopt:jar:1.0.12-brew:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss:jboss-common-core:jar:2.2.11.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.deployers:jboss-deployers-client-spi:jar:2.0.5.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.man:jboss-managed:jar:2.0.0.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.deployers:jboss-deployers-core-spi:jar:2.0.5.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-deployment:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-common:jar:client:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-core:jar:client:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.cache:jbosscache-core:jar:3.0.0.CR4:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.aspects:jboss-remoting-aspects:jar:1.0.1.CR4:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.aspects:jboss-transaction-aspects:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.aspects:jboss-security-aspects:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.cluster:jboss-ha-server-api:jar:1.1.0.CR4:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-async:jar:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-security:jar:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-proxy:jar:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-proxy-clustered:jar:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-transactions:jar:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-proxy:jar:client:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-proxy-clustered:jar:client:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-security:jar:client:1.0.0:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-cluster:jar:jboss-ha-legacy-client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.cluster:jboss-ha-server-cache-spi:jar:1.1.0.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.cluster:jboss-ha-server-cache-jbc:jar:1.1.0.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-iiop:jar:client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact apache-avalon:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.5:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.integration:jboss-classloading-spi:jar:5.0.3.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-main:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.integration:jboss-integration:jar:5.0.3.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-j2se:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.javaee:jboss-javaee:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-management:jar:jsr77-client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-cluster:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-jdk:jar:2.0.5.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-main:jar:client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss:jboss-mdr:jar:2.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact jboss.messaging:jboss-messaging:jar:1.4.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:2.5.0.SP2:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.security:jboss-security-spi:jar:2.0.2.SP6:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-system:jar:client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:jar:2.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.integration:jboss-profileservice-spi:jar:5.0.3.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.man:jboss-metatype:jar:2.0.0.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.microcontainer:jboss-dependency:jar:2.0.4.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.microcontainer:jboss-aop-mc-int:jar:2.0.4.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-system-jmx:jar:client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-jmx:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-j2se:test-jar:tests:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-mbeans:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.test:jboss-test:jar:1.1.3.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact jboss.profiler.jvmti:jboss-profiler-jvmti:jar:1.0.0.CR5:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-server-manager:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.security:jbosssx-client:jar:2.0.2.SP6:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-server:jar:jmx-invoker-adaptor-client:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.naming:jnp-client:jar:5.0.1.GA:compile
08.12.10 11:41:58 MEZ: Missing artifact org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logging:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Best wishes,

Daniel

Answer (score 4):

In my case this worked for jboss4.2.3:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public 
        Repository Group</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-deprecated</id>
        <name>JBoss Deprecated</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/
        </url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved.. i added 2 other repositories. Now my respository list looks like this:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-deprecated</id>
            <name>JBoss Deprecated</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-maven2-brew</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven 2 Brew Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2-brew/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this repository https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/ to your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I still have some errors about missing artifacts

Comment: Thats the old repository (/maven2/) which is deprecated. To get the .pom file for the client is no problem. The problem is to get all the required .jar files